# How to Read a pre-built Text File in a Windows Phone Application

Tags: file-io, windows-phone-7.1

I've been trying to read a pre-built file with Car Maintenance tips, there's one in each line of my "Tips.txt" file. I've tried to follow around 4 or 5 different approaches but It's not working, it compiles but I get an exception. Here's what I've got:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("Tips.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    (App.Current as App).MyTips.Insert(new DoubleNode(line));
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream", from the info inside the 2nd using statement. I tried with the build action of my "Tips.txt" set to resource, and content, yet I get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say pre-built, do you mean you've already written it to Isolated Storage or that you've added it to the project directory in Visual Studio?

Comment: Added it to the project directory in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've added it to your project directory, you can't read it using `Isolated Storage` methods. There are various ways you can load the file. One way would be to set the text file's build type to `Resource`, then read it in as a stream:

```
//Replace 'MyProject' with the name of your XAP/Project
Stream txtStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/MyProject;component/myTextFile.txt", 
                                                             UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtStream))
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks :D